# Data cleaning history table - to build accurate history (startdate enddate)

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a history table in SQL Server which has `startdate` and `enddate`. I have to remove the duplicated record and populate another table with accurate history (`startdate` and `enddate`).

Below is the table - `ProductType` column  is not relevant for the business. I have to build the table with the columns `Product`, `ProductPrice`, `StartDate` and `EndDate` where if any of the duplicated records is there, then the `startdate= min(startdate)` of the particular product and `productprice` for the continuous period. and `enddate` is `max(enddate)` of the particular product and `productprice` for the continuous period.

Example - currently table looks like this:

| Product | Product Type | Product Price | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 100 | 2018-09-18 | 2019-09-09 |
| A | C | 100 | 2019-09-09 | 2019-12-09 |
| A | B | 100 | 2019-12-08 | 2019-12-22 |
| A | C | 150 | 2019-12-23 | 2019-12-24 |
| A | B | 100 | 2019-12-25 | 2019-12-28 |

The issue I am facing is records are reduced to 2 by taking the `startdate` of 1 st record and end date of the last record of the product price 100 .-
i.e not the accurate history

| Product | Product Type | Product Price | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | 100 | 2018-09-18 | 2019-12-28 |
| A |  | 150 | 2019-12-23 | 2019-12-24 |

This is the  actual  expected history

| Product | Product Type | Product Price | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | 100 | 2018-09-18 | 2019-12-22 |
| A |  | 150 | 2019-12-23 | 2019-12-24 |
| A |  | 100 | 2019-12-25 | 2019-12-28 |

Comment: Add original data in same format as the rest of the tables. Also, please attach your query, even if it's wrong, it might be a good start

Comment: Sure .I will add that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic gaps and islands problem:

```sql
select  Product, [Product Price], MIN(startdate), max(enddate)
FROM    (
    select  SUM(flag) over(partition by product order by startdate) as grp
    ,   *
    from (
        select *
        , case when lag([product price]) over(partition by product order by startdate) <> [product price] then 1 else 0 end as flag
        from (
            VALUES  (N'A', N'B', 100, N'2018-09-18', N'2019-09-09')
            ,   (N'A', N'C', 100, N'2019-09-09', N'2019-12-09')
            ,   (N'A', N'B', 100, N'2019-12-08', N'2019-12-22')
            ,   (N'A', N'C', 150, N'2019-12-23', N'2019-12-24')
            ,   (N'A', N'B', 100, N'2019-12-25', N'2019-12-28')
        ) t (Product,[Product Type],[Product Price],StartDate,EndDate)
        ) x
    ) x
group by product, grp, [Product Price]
```

It's a three-step solution.

1. Create a flag that increments every time something you need to group on changes.
2. Summarize the flag ordered by date to create a group
3. Group by that group

Comment: Thank you @siggemannen .. This works well

Answer (score -1):

If i understand correctly, the below query will work for you.

```
select 
  product, 
  product_type, 
  product_price, 
  min(start_date) as start_date, 
  max(end_date) as end_date 
from producttype 
group by product, product_type, product_price;
```

Comment: this will not work.In SQL can't keep  a field in select which is not either in the aggreation or in the group by statement.

Comment: Ah! did it in mysql thinking that it works in SQL server as well. As you edited the expected result, what is the ProductType for Price 100 in the output you are looking for?